# Xpath results in empty variable

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I am very confused about the property mediator in the WSO2 Micro intergator suite. There is a field that I need to extract using Xpath and then send to AWS SQS. The following is the document from which I try to extract the field (note that I cropped the bottom half of the document).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <Waybill
            xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Waybill-2"
            xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:eba="http://ns.tln.nl/eba/schemas/1-0/"
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Waybill-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd1-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Waybill-2.1.xsd http://ns.tln.nl/eba/schemas/1-0-1/EBA-Extensions.xsd">
            <ext:UBLExtensions>
                <ext:UBLExtension>
                    <ext:ExtensionContent>
                        <eba:ReplyAddress>
                            <eba:Webservice>
                                <eba:WebserviceEndPoint>http://www.google.com
                                </eba:WebserviceEndPoint>
                                <eba:Username>123</eba:Username>
                                <eba:Password>123
                                </eba:Password>
                            </eba:Webservice>
                        </eba:ReplyAddress>
                    </ext:ExtensionContent>
                </ext:UBLExtension>
                <ext:UBLExtension>
                    <ext:ExtensionContent>
                        <eba:ReplyAddress>
                            <eba:EmailAddress>some@address.com</eba:EmailAddress>
                        </eba:ReplyAddress>
                    </ext:ExtensionContent>
                </ext:UBLExtension>
            </ext:UBLExtensions>
```

I'm looking to parse the "Waybill" part. No matter what I try with the property, the result is either going to be an error (syntactical) or an empty result.

Examples of non-working code I tried thus far:

```
<property expression="//s:Body/Waybill" name="wayb" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />

<property expression="$:Body/Waybill" name="messageBody" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Waybill-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:eba="http://ns.tln.nl/eba/schemas/1-0/" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Waybill-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd1-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Waybill-2.1.xsd http://ns.tln.nl/eba/schemas/1-0-1/EBA-Extensions.xsd"/>

<property expression="//Waybill" name="messageBody" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Waybill-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:eba="http://ns.tln.nl/eba/schemas/1-0/" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Waybill-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd1-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Waybill-2.1.xsd http://ns.tln.nl/eba/schemas/1-0-1/EBA-Extensions.xsd"/>

<property expression="//Waybill" name="messageBody" scope="default" type="STRING" />
```

Note however that I can easily grab the body field which DOES work:

```
<property expression="$body" name="messageBody" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try expression="$body//Waybill" (note the double '/')

Comment: @Samisa: yes, I forgot to mention but that was one of the options I already tried. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: I stumbled on this question somehow so don't know anything about wso2. But just looking at your xml and xpath expressions, it seems you may have run into a problem with namespaces. Can you try `//*[local-name()="Waybill"]`?

Comment: @JackFleeting You sir, are a life saver! I only had to add the single quotes around the Waybill part (because of it being in an expression) but after it would just pick up the waybill part. Thank you so much and please create an answer out of this so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: @Ludo21South Glad it helped! See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here (as is the case with many xml snippets) is the use of namespaces; as the experts will tell you, they are necessary - but, in my opinion, a necessary evil....

One way to deal with them is to disregard them when possible; that, in turn, can be done by using xpath's `local-name()` function.

Or, in this case:

```
//*[local-name()='Waybill']
```